# Undefined property error in one to many

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make an app where you can administer office materials, invoices etc. So my Order has many Materials and one Invoice.

My Materials table has:

```
id | name | count_all | count_current | price_unit
```

My Orders table has:

```
id | count_order | material_id | invoice_id
```

My Invoices table has:

```
id | number | inc_date | scan_name | sum
```

My Material model looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Material extends Model
{
    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Order', 'material_id');
    }
    public function expenditure(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Expenditure');
    }
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'count_all', 'count_current', 'price_unit',
    ];
}
```

My Order model looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    public function invoice(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Invoice');
    }

    public function material(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Material');
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'count_order',
    ];
}
```

My OrderController looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\order;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class orderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show a list of all of the application's orders.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show()
    {
        $orders = DB::table('orders')->get();

        return view('order', ['orders' => $orders]);
    }

    public function insert(Request $request){

        $order = new order;

        $order->count_order = $request->count_order;

        $order->save();
        return redirect('/order');
    }

    public function edit(order $order){

        return view('edit_order', compact('order'));   
    }

    public function update(Request $request, order $order){
        if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
            $order->delete();
            return redirect('/order');
        }
        else{
            $order->count_order = $request->count_order;

            $order->save();
            return redirect('/order');
       }
    }
}
```

So when trying to access DB I will use fuction "show" in my route.

And piece of my blade that "cause problem":

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$order->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->material->name}}</td> //this is causing the Undefined property problem when trying to display material name instead of id
        <td>{{$order->invoice_id}}</td> //this should look similar to the one above but since it doesn't work I didn't change it
        <td>{{$order->count_order}}</td>
        <td>    
            <form action="/order/{{$order->id}}">
                <button type="submit" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edycja zamówienia</button>
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

So when I'm trying to display Material name in blade (like above) it returns the following error:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$materials (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\petition_app\resources\views\order.blade.php)
```

Comment: Try this code, only change first instead of get,    public function show()
    {
        $orders = DB::table('orders')->first();

        return view('order', ['orders' => $orders]);
    }

Comment: @parthu_panther when I changed it I get "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: also edit this line in your blade file:-  <td>{{$order->material[name]}}</td>    ' ->' is used for object and '[]' is used for array and since your query result is array you need to change that line as stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `belongsTo()` relationship from `order` to `material`. Change your `relationship` to:

```
public function material(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Material','material_id');
}
```

You are using `query builder`, you need to use laravel `eloquent` to access `relationship` model data. Change your controller `logic` code like:

```
$orders = Order::all();
```

Comment: Wait... so I want to make sure - I have to change the function in Order.php model right?

Comment: goddammit Im an idiot. Care to explain what my pea brain did wrong?

Comment: @korni please have a look again

Comment: thanks for clarifications. It seems I misunderstood something when creating Models. So where do I need to put "hasOne"/"hasMany"? - because they clearly do not belong to Order.php Model

Comment: let me clarify a little more, use hasOne and hasMany when the foreign key are in the related table like in your material table have a relationship with order table has hasOne or hasMany relationship as material_id i mean the foreign key are in order table means in the related table from material perspective and belongsTo for alternate

Comment: so to specify: Orders table has foreign keys and hasOne/Many - needs to be in corresponding table Models right?

Comment: yes, relationship function will be on the model which table you are referring